# Try to access empty JavaScript array without error

Tags: javascript

I'm trying wrongly to access an empty json array:

```
json.shift().totalCount;
```

but I get no error message. I'm wondering why. If I step in with Dev Tools I get to
[tslib.es6.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwGMz.png)

The error message in the catch block says:

> Cannot read property 'totalCount' of undefined" stack: "TypeError:
>   Cannot read property 'totalCount' of undefined↵ at...

Before fixing the issue I would like to understand, why I do not get an error

PS: I'm using Babel, WebPack and TypeScript

EDIT: To clarify: I get an error if I open the Dev Tools and go to the line where the error is catched. But I get no error in the console. I'm wondering why this is so? Why would a library swallow an error.

Thx

Comment: so do not do it in one line.... check to see if it is there before you reference it....

Comment: Before fixing the issue I would like to understand, why I do not get an error

Comment: Your question is a little confusing, you say `but I get no error message`, and then say `the error message  in the catch block says`,.  So do you get an error or not?

Comment: I'm guessing you have no error because the error is getting caught somewhere?

Comment: "why I do not get an error " Well looks like you do have an error by the text you included in the yellow box which you said is in the catch block which catches errors....

Comment: _“why I do not get an error”_ - as long as what shift has returned is _any_ kind of object, you can “access” undefined properties on it, and will get “undefined” as return.

Comment: you must be getting error. check in your browser console. Try different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You are saying no error is showing, but you are also saying you are finding it in a catch block in the code somewhere.

Is it being logged to the console (`console.log`) in the catch block?

If not, then it will not show up in the browser console.

However, the debugger you are using to find the error is showing you the error because this is what debuggers are for.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstandings. I get an error if I open the Dev Tools and go to the line where the error is catched. But I get no error in the console. I'm wondering why this is so? Why would a library swallow an error.

Comment: If it's caught, why would you expect an error in the console?

Comment: Because it's caught by a library (tslib.es6.js from MS) and not by my code. I would like to handle errors myself. Why would someone do this? What is the benefit of code like this?

Comment: It's an expected error the library owners decided to handle, because apparently it can be handled and does not need to bubble up to the user.  If you want to know why, ask *them*.

Comment: You can catch an error and handle it as a library owner. Why would they do this? Because for some errors they don't need to expose it to the user. It is the same reason you don't need to know how jQuery works to use it, you just use it as the documentation teaches you to. For example, if the library in question was for streaming some kind of video, instead of throwing/logging an error when the stream fails to load, it may do _something else_, like retry the load, replace it with a failure image, etc. There are reasons for these things.